# Convergence of a series and switching integral sign and summation symbol

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, power-series

I am stuck to prove the following result and i need an argument to do it. (It is not necessary possible.) Here is the problem:

Let $r > 0$,$n,p,p_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > p > p_0$ and $p-p_0 \geq 2$,$\mathbf{Z}$ be a random vector $\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a vector space of dimension $n-p_0$ and let $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be the projection matrix from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ into $M$.  To simplify the notation, let's write $m = n-p_0 + 1$ and so $m > 1$. Let us suppose also that $\mathbf{Z}$ has a continuous probability distribution.
I want to prove that is possible to invert the summation and the integral symbol in the following expression:

$$
\int_0^\infty \sum_0^\infty \frac{[||H \mathbf{Z}||r]^{2k}}{k!}\frac{e^{-\frac{||\mathbf{Z}||^2}{2\tau^2}}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}}{\tau^{m + 2k}2^{2k}\Gamma(k + \frac{p-p_0}{2})}d\tau.
$$

The first condition that has to be fulfilled is that the series must converge almost everywhere. i used two methods:

**First method: Ratio test**

The ratio $R$ between the $k+1$-th element and the $k$-th element of the series is:
$$
R(k) = 
\frac{[||H \mathbf{Z}||r]^{2k+2}}{(k+1)!}\frac{e^{-\frac{||\mathbf{Z}||^2}{2\tau^2}}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}}{\tau^{m + 2k+2}2^{2k+2}\Gamma(k+1 + \frac{p-p_0}{2})}
\frac{k!\tau^{m + 2k}2^{2k}\Gamma(k + \frac{p-p_0}{2})}{[||H \mathbf{Z}||r]^{2k}e^{-\frac{||\mathbf{Z}||^2}{2\tau^2}}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}}
$$

$$
=
\frac{[||H \mathbf{Z}||r]^{2}}{(k+1)}\frac{\Gamma(k + \frac{p-p_0}{2})}{\tau^{ 2}2^{2}\Gamma(k+1 + \frac{p-p_0}{2})}
$$

and we have that for $r < \infty$ and $\tau >0$ $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}R(k) = 0$.

**Second method**

Because $p-p_0 \geq 2$ so $k+ \frac{p-p_0}{2} \geq 1$ and so $\Gamma(k+ \frac{p-p_0}{2})\geq 1$ for any $k \in\mathbb{N}$. This means that:
$$
\frac{[||H \mathbf{Z}||r]^{2k}}{k!}\frac{e^{-\frac{||\mathbf{Z}||^2}{2\tau^2}}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}}{\tau^{m + 2k}2^{2k}\Gamma(k + \frac{p-p_0}{2})}
\leq
\frac{[||H \mathbf{Z}||r]^{2k}}{k!}\frac{e^{-\frac{||\mathbf{Z}||^2}{2\tau^2}}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}}{\tau^{m + 2k}2^{2k}}:= a_k
$$
for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then computing the series on the $a_k$, we obtain:
$$
\sum a_k = \frac{1}{\tau^m}e^{-\frac{||\mathbf{Z}||^2}{2\tau^2}}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}
e^{\frac{[||H \mathbf{Z}||r]^{2}}{4\tau^2}}.
$$

For $r < \infty$ the serie converges for any $\tau \geq 0$ almost everywhere, but in particular for $\tau = 0$, since
$$
e^{-\frac{||\mathbf{Z}||^2}{2\tau^2}+ \frac{[||H \mathbf{Z}||r]^{2}}{4\tau^2}} 
=
e^{-\frac{1}{2\tau^2}(||\mathbf{Z}||^2-\frac{[||H \mathbf{Z}||r]^{2}}{2})}
$$
almost everywhere, because
and $||\mathbf{Z}||^2 > \frac{[||H \mathbf{Z}||r]^{2}}{2}$ almost everywhere. Then this implies that my first series converges for any $\tau\geq 0$ and $0<r<\infty$.

I would be very grateful if someone could say me if he agrees with my reasoning and if he has some idea to show it for $r\rightarrow \infty$. Maybe i can also precise that $r$ is the norm of the mean of the distribution of $H\mathbf{Z}$, i.e. $r = ||\mathbb{E}[H\mathbf{Z}]||$.

For the inversion series-integral, i want to apply a theorem that i have found saying that if the terms in the series are all measurable and the series converges then we can inverse the series and the integral. If i choose the measurable space $([0,\infty], \mathcal{B})$ for $\tau$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel set on the positive real line, then all the terms are effectively measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry: all terms of your series are positive, so the partial sums are increasing, and you can interchange summation and integration due to the monotone convergence theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You are right. However I still have to show that the series converges for $\tau = 0$ and for $r '=' \infty$.